# path partition in python

Tags: python, https, mysql-python

For path partition in python, how to use self.path.partition() to distinguish different paths in the best way possible?
For example, 
`/match?pid1=&pid2=&A=[]&B=[]`
`/match/[cid]/C/[pid]?points=`
`/match/[cid]/end` 
`/match/[cid]/D/[pid]`
I've tried to use `path, _, query_string = self.path.partition('?')` and `'/'`, follow by `query = parse_qs(query_string, keep_blank_values=True)`but hardly distinguish the paths and extract the information, like pid and cid, that I need for mysql. I'm trying to use the partition result to proceed with next `'if'` statement.  
I'm wondering how can I break them down perfectly and extract the info so that I can use `'if'` to proceed different command? Will update if I figure out something.

Comment: What library are you using? I think you should add more context and code examples

Comment: For the example above, I need A) pid1 and pid2 along with A and B.  B)cid and pid with points. C) cid D) pid and cid  to search and update the value in mysql.